# Are composite unique keys indexed in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, unique-index

I have a **`UserSkills`** table having three columns: **`id`** *(PK)*, **`userId`** *(FK)* and **`skillId`** *(FK)*.

I want to enforce a composite unique constraint on a combination of **`userId`** and **`skillId`**. And for faster lookups, I want composite indexing on **`(userId, skillId)`**.

As far as I know, MySQL automatically indexes unique columns. But, all the examples I have seen and my own implementations so far involve single-column unique constraints. I want to know if MySQL indexes composite unique keys as well. And if it does, is it treated as a normal multi-column index or not?

For normal multi-column indexes, according to the MySQL reference manual:

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
> index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if
> you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed
> search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

In a nutshell, I want to find out if I should create a multi-column index of (userId, skillId) after declaring the aforementioned multi-column unique constraint involving them, or would that be simply redundant and hence not required?

Comment: Just add a unique index on the two fields.  
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name(index_column_1,index_column_2,...);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for your fields, `id` (PK), `userId` (FK) and `skillId` (FK),
mysql will automatically create an index on `(id)` (unique), and index on `(userId)` (non-unique) and an index on `(skillId)` (non-unique).

You still need an additional unique index on `(userId, skillId)`.

This could replace the non-unique index on `(userId)` because the optimizer can use the `(userId, skillId)` index whenever it needs to look up by `userId`.  However, creating and dropping indexes when the index is used by a foreign key in mysql can be cumbersome, so you might just want to add the composite unique index.

Comment: So, basically you are suggesting that in place of creating a composite unique constraint on `(userId, skillId)` and another composite index on the same, I am better off combing the two and creating a unique index on `(userId, skillId)`. Am I right? If yes, this would ensure uniqueness of the combination and index them as well as per normal composite index, which would be the perfect solution that I am looking for.

Comment: I would say yes.  Uniqueness constraints in RDBMS are just creating a unique index.  For that you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

Q: `want to know if MySQL indexes composite unique keys as well. And if it does, is it treated as a normal multi-column index or not`

Yes, see:

> MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an index is created. Exception: NDB Cluster requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on the foreign key column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-foreign-key.html

FloridaDBA commented:

`Just add a unique index on the two fields. CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name(index_column_1,index_column_2,...)`

This is possible, but I won't recommend "just" doing this, because like the manual states that.

> any **leftmost** prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows

It depends on how your queries are built and how you are implementing your indexes, but is it possible can see a performance drop because it cannot always use you the composite index.

To have get an idea if a composite index is a good idea, you must study all the queries that are using the tables and check how things like `WHERE` clauses uses these columns. Refactoring other the queries (if any) might help the optimal use of the composite keys.

For more information about this read this article and study the given examples.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: You are right about creating unique index on multiple columns being good for some cases and bad for others. But I have specific queries involving both `userId` and `skillId` and hence the composite indexing would make sense. I wanted to clear my concepts as well on how MySQL behaves in more intrinsic cases like this.